# Create hidden folders using Github API to store files just like it does in UI drag-n-drop feature

Tags: github, github-api

I am creating a `log file` and uploading it to my GitHub repository using Github API. The URL of this file is then I am attaching to the existing issue, programmatically. This creates a new folder in my repo to store the files.

The **problem** here is that I don't want to create any folder in the repo itself which contains all the logs. What I want that this log folder to be hidden in the repo UI.

For example, when we drag and drop a file in the existing issue, the file stores at the following location:

```
https://github.com/{org-name}/{repo-name}/files/{random-number}/test.txt
```

The location for `files` or that `{random-number}` cannot be accessed from the UI. Although you can access the file `test.txt` from the URL.

Is there a similar way to achieve the same using Github API?